# Running Python from a USB stick on Chrome OS

Tags: linux, usb, python, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I have been thinking about running using Python on my chrome book. Is it possible to run Python form a USB key on my Chromebook?

If so what would the steps be?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to enter "Developer Mode" by setting a little switch on the side of the chrome book:

http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/samsung-series-5-chromebook

http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/poking-around-your-chrome-os-device

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-y6p9tAgGE

And compile python for chrome (or at leaset link static on a similar linux) as described here:

https://github.com/helloandre/cr48#readme

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to run Python on ChromeOS unless you take the source code and built it with extra pkg.
It's true that ChromeOS is based on Linux but it's very thin layer and lots of lib/pkg where left out so it will be secure/fast.

Comment: Why is it not possible?

Comment: It's not possible 'out of the box'... sorry if it wasn't clear.